# Python: Trying to approximate 'portion_saved' in the following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, bisection

```
#This part asks for the user input
annual_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary:"))

#Declaring all the variables
total_cost = 1000000
High = 1.0
Low = 0.0
portion_saved = (High +Low)/2.0
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
r = 0.04 #annual investment return
portion_down_payment = 0.25
num_guesses = 0
epsilon = 100
total_saving = 0.0
months = 0

#Calculations next
while abs(total_cost - total_saving) >= epsilon:
    num_guesses += 1
    total_saving = 0.0

    while total_saving < (total_cost*portion_down_payment):
        monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
        monthly_saving = monthly_salary*portion_saved
        total_saving += (monthly_saving + total_saving*r/12)
        months += 1
        if months%6 == 0:
            annual_salary += annual_salary*semi_annual_raise

    if (total_saving < total_cost):
        Low = portion_saved
    else:
        High = portion_saved
    portion_saved = (Low+High)/2.0

print("Best savings rate:", portion_saved)
print("Number of steps:", num_guesses)
```

But the code enters an infinite loop. When checked using a print command, it turns out that the 'portion_saved' variable takes the value 1.0 on each iteration. But I can't figure out why is this happening. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

your code always goes into the if statement, so you are always setting Low to be portion_saved:

```
    1: Low = 0, portion_saved= 1/2
    2: Low = 1/2, portion_saved= 1.5/2
    3: Low = .75, portion_saved= 1.75/2
    4: Low = .875, portion_saved= 1.875/2
    5: and so on....
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it. Had to make two corrections.

1. Multiplied the 'total_cost' by 'portions_down_payment' as I really had to calculate the rate to pay the downpayment.
2. I reset the value of annual sal for each iteration to the initial value.

The final code looks like this:

```
#This part asks for the user input
starting_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary:"))

#Declaring all the variables
total_cost = 1000000
High = 1.0
Low = 0.0
portion_saved = (High +Low)/2.0
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
r = 0.04 #annual investment return
portion_down_payment = 0.25
num_guesses = 0
epsilon = 100
total_saving = 0.0
months = 36
print(portion_saved)

#Calculations next
while abs(total_cost*portion_down_payment - total_saving) >= epsilon:
    num_guesses += 1
    total_saving = 0.0
    annual_salary = starting_salary
    for i in range (months):
        monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
        monthly_saving = monthly_salary*portion_saved
        total_saving += (monthly_saving + total_saving*r/12)
        if i%6 == 0:
            annual_salary += annual_salary*semi_annual_raise

    if (total_saving > total_cost*portion_down_payment):
        High = portion_saved
    else:
        Low = portion_saved

    portion_saved = (Low+High)/2.0

print("Best savings rate:", portion_saved)
print("Number of steps:", num_guesses)
```